# interop class wants arrays of type [*]

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, marshalling, labview

I have a Labview `interop assembly` which wants `string[* ]`, `int[* ]` and `customType[*]` for various structs and methods.

For example, this is the declaration of a struct in the metadata:

```
public struct AppImage__32Properties
{
   ...
    public FPGA__32Properties[] fPGA__32Properties;
...}
```

*fPGA__32Properties is an array of struct.*

Now I want to assign to it an empty array of the same type
(Its instance is not initialized) and then proceed with filling its fields.

```
AppInfoDummy[0].appImage__32Properties.fPGA__32Properties =  
          new FPGA__32Properties[1];
```

but it results in

> **"Cannot implicitly convert type 'DeployImage_RAD.FPGA_32Properties[]' to
>   DeployImage_RAD.FPGA_32Properties[*]"**.

I have the same problem with other `struct`, int and `string arrays` of `type [*]` from that `interop` assembly.

Apparently `someType[*]` is an array which has its starting index somewhere else than zero. ( [What does System.Double[*] mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125903/what-does-system-double-mean)) and there is a way to access it values. But how do I assign a value to it?

BTW: I worked on this project in Visual Studio 2012 Profession before and this problem did not occur. Now I use Visual Studio 2015 Prof.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Array` class directly. C# can't really help you much in this case (VB.NET will make this a lot easier, since it supports custom lower and higher bounds natively, unlike C#).

As a sample, if you need a double array going from 1 to 10, it would be defined as:

```
Array doubleArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), new []{ 10 }, new []{ 1 });
```

Accessing an index also goes through `Array`:

```
doubleArray.SetValue(42d, 3); // Set value 42d at index 3
doubleArray.GetValue(3); // Get value at index 3 (offset 2 in this case)
```

It might be a good idea to make a safe wrapper around (or a statically typed copy of) the `Array` instance, just to make it easier to work with, and more explicit which `Array` is which.

Comment: Thanks Luaan. Visual Studio accepts this and I can build the solution. However, I couldn't get to test it yet because I have another problem with string[*] in that code.  
When I tested it successfully, I will mark your answer.

Comment: Hi Luaan, I cannot create an instance of type string[ * ] with Array.CreateInstance. Some of those arrays are string[ * ].

Comment: @Simorgh It works fine for me. Are you having trouble initializing the values in the string array? Are you getting some exception?