# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[*]' to type 'System.Int32[]'.'

Tags: vb.net

I'm editing a legacy program in VB when most of my computer programming experience is in C#. The program in question compiles fine but when running I get to a certain function call to a DLL file and I get the following:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[*]' to type 'System.Int32[]'.'
```

The arguments that are causing the issue are Dim'd As Integer. The function wants the arguments ByRef As Array. However, even when redefining the arguments As Array it says:

```
'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[*]' to type 'System.Array'.'
```

EDIT

To try and give "minimal, complete, and verifiable example" as suggested by [ItsPete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579123/itspete) here is some code.

I am using [DA 1 OPC Wrapper DLL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/490072/DA-1-OPC-Wrapper-DLL-and-Client-Example?msg=5689705#xx5689705xx). This project is something I had to add a few part numbers to, not something I wrote from scratch.

```
Dim ConnectedOPCServer As New OPCAutomation.OPCServer
Public OPCItemCollection As OPCAutomation.OPCItems
Public gConnectedGroup As OPCAutomation.OPCGroup
Dim ConnectedServerGroups As OPCAutomation.OPCGroups
Dim ItemServerHandles() As Integer
Dim ItemServerErrors() As Integer
Dim OPCItemIDs() As String
ConnectedOPCServer = New OPCAutomation.OPCServer
ConnectedOPCServer.Connect("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5")
ConnectedServerGroups = ConnectedOPCServer.OPCGroups
gConnectedGroup = ConnectedServerGroups.Add("Group1")
gConnectedGroup.UpdateRate = 200
gConnectedGroup.IsSubscribed = True
Call Add_OPC_Items() 'This adds tags to the OPC collection by assigning elements of the OPCItemIDs array to tag names
OPCItemCollection = gConnectedGroup.OPCItems
OPCItemCollection.DefaultIsActive = True
OPCItemCollection.AddItems(ItemCount, OPCItemIDs, ClientHandles, ItemServerHandles, ItemServerErrors)
```

I think that is all that is needed. Like I said...I just expected to add a few part numbers to a drop down selection and not have to dig neck deep into debugging this so I'm kinda out of my depth.

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) that might be promising. But that looks like it is for C# or C++ and not VB. I dont know how there are many duplicates...searching for Int32[*] didn't return much between Google and Stackoverflow's own search.

And holy crap [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) that is like a day of reading.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Many duplicates, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23196890/17034).

Comment: See also this article: [Understanding Classic COM Interoperability With .NET Applications](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990/Understanding-Classic-COM-Interoperability-With-NE), more specifically, the *Using COM Collections from .NET Applications* section.

Comment: Updated main post with responses.

Hopefully things will make more sense after a night of sleep.

Comment: ... that's why a added *more specifically...*. It's a *compendium* to what's described in Hans Passant's notes (it's a good reading, overall, anyway). There's not much of a difference if you're coding in C# or VB.Net when it comes to COM Interop.

Comment: I don't remember if the interop marshaller will adjust array characteristics or not when it marshals the ref back, but you can create a array of type `System.Int32[*]` with `Dim ItemServerHandles As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Int32), {2}, {1})`.  This create an array with Length = 2 and a lower bound of 1.

Comment: Hans's cited answer describes what happens in the .NET runtime and thus is not specific to VB or C# in that respect.  It may be easier to access elements from VB; it's been a while since I rebelled against the misdesign of forcing a 0 lower bound in .NET, so I don't remember what happened when I was making one-bounded arrays using `Array.CreateInstance`.  TnTinMn's code is how you create a non-vector rank-1 `System.Array`.